# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'

Tags: aws-lambda, psycopg2, python-3.11

I have used docker to create a zip package for psycopg2. Below are the commands,

```
pip3 install psycopg2 -t layer/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ 
cd layer
zip -r layerpsycopg2.zip *
```

Have uploaded this zip file in AWS Lambda layer successfully.
My AWS Lambda function is on Python 3.11. Tried importing psycopg2 in lambda function. Getting below error,

```
{
 "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'",
 "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
 "requestId": "xxxx",
 "stackTrace": []
}
```

Have also tried aws-psycopg2 library but getting same error.

Comment: This can happen when there is a python version mismatch between the lambda and the layer.

Comment: I have installed Python3.11 in the layer and selected same version in AWS Lambda.

Comment: What does you import statment look like in the handler?

Comment: @RossBush - 

import psycopg2

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Hi")